# Is it possible to send to another address using replace-by-fee in either Bitcoin Core or Electrum?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, electrum, replace-by-fee

In Bitcoin Core (or Electrum), when sending a transaction with "Enable Replace-by-fee" checked, is it possible to resend the transaction (before it was mined) with a higher fee AND to another address?

Answer (score 5):

Such a transaction is standard and would relay. However neither the Bitcoin Core wallet (via the `bumpfee` command) nor the Electrum wallet (via the GUI) would create such transaction.

More information about fee bumping in the Bitcoin Core wallet can be found [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/12271).